# Algebraic Geometry: How to compute the intersection number for concrete examples?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am working on the following exercise:

> Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field and let $x \in K$.
>
> 1. Compute $i_x(P,Y)$ for $P := Y^2-X^2(X+1)$ and $x \in Z(P,Y)$.
> 2. Compute $i_x(P,L)$ for an arbitrary line $L$.
> 3. Compute $i_x(P,Y)$ for $Q := Y^2-X^3$ and $x \in Z(Q,Y)$.

Here are the required definitions:

> We defined $Z(P)$ as the set of zeroes of a given polynomial $P$. $m_x$ is the kernel of the evaluation homomorphism $\varepsilon_x: K[X,Y] \ni P \mapsto P(x) \in K$. The intersection number for a given $x \in K$ and $P,Q \in K[X,Y]$ is defined as
>
> $$i_x(P,Q) := \dim_K(K[X,Y]_{m_x}/(P,Q)_{K[X,Y]_{m_x}}).$$

I do not see through these formulas yet. Could you please give me a hint on how to start here?

Comment: Write down the quotient you want to compute. For instance, the first one, if we take $x=(0,0)$ then the quotient is $k[x,y]_{(x,y)}/(y,y^2-x^2(x-1))$. But this is isomorphic to $k[x]_{(x)}/(x^2(x-1))$ by sending $y\mapsto 0$, and now since $x-1$ is a unit this is isomorphic to $k[x]_{(x)}/(x^2)$, which is isomorphic to $k[x]/(x^2)$ which clearly has dimension two. Is that helpful?

Comment: Here are some other posts with examples of computing intersection numbers: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2120270/intersection-number-between-two-projective-curves), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1696061/checking-the-intersection-multiplicity-for-two-curves), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4033736/finding-intersection-multiplicities-of-a-tangent-line-and-a-quartic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you would enjoy knowing some of the algebraic properties of the number $i_x(P,Q)$:

$$i_x(P,Q) = i_x(Q,P)$$
$$i_x(P, Q_1Q_2) = i_x(P,Q_1)+i_x(P,Q_2)$$
$$i_x(P+QR,Q) = i_x(P,Q)$$

Which allow you to simplify a lot of problems. Sometimes it is easier to deal with power series, to use inverses for polynomials, in which case you can use that

$$i_x(P,Q) = \dim_K ( K[[X,Y]]/(P,Q))$$

Note that the questions you pose are not difficult to answer because the intersection multiplicity of a curve and a line can be obtained parametrizing the line and seeing the multiplicity of the zero that you obtain:

1. the line is $t \mapsto (t,0)$, so substituting in the equation of $P$ you get $-t^2(t+1)=0$. therefore you have intersection multiplicirty 2 at $t=0$ and $1$ at $t=-1$
2. the line is again $t \mapsto (t,0)$ so you obtain $-t^3=0$, which implies multiplicity 3